# How to I correctly add brackets to this code

Tags: javascript, readability, semantics

This code trims whitespace, (fyi: it's credited to be very fast)

```
function wSpaceTrim(s){
    var start = -1,
    end = s.length;
    while (s.charCodeAt(--end) < 33 );  //here
    while (s.charCodeAt(++start) < 33 );  //here also 
    return s.slice( start, end + 1 );
}
```

The while loops don't have brackets, *how would i correctly add brackets to this code?*

```
while(iMean){
  // like this;
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loop bodies are empty (the actual thing that happens is the increment/decrement operation within the loop condition), so simply add `{}`:

```
while (s.charCodeAt(--end) < 33 ){}
while (s.charCodeAt(++start) < 33 ){}
```

A longer, and probably easier to read version of the same while loop would be:

```
end = end - 1;
while (s.charCodeAt(end) < 33 )
{
    end = end - 1;
}
start = start + 1;
while (s.charCodeAt(start) < 33 )
{
    start = start + 1;
}
```

Comment: if they're empty are they doing anything?

Comment: Oh, they're changing the variables `end` and `start` aren't they?

Comment: Maybe add a comment like this: { /* explaining what you're doing won't harm */ }

Comment: Yep, the side effects are inside the expression and not the body

Comment: ah, google closure gave me a warning and I needed to check this out : )  
Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Mohammad if you add a test at the end so that you only call "slice" if there are actually spaces to be trimmed, it will really speed up the case of no trimming necessary.

Comment: @Pointy, but doest `test()` search through all the string for the pattern, wouldn't that actually be slower than just committing to a slice that returns everything?

Comment: No no I don't mean "test()", I mean "a test"; in other words, a comparison to see if the call to "slice()" will actually do anything.

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't need brackets, but it does need an option to use a native trim method.

Opera, Firefox and Chrome all have a native string prototype trim function-
the other browsers could add it as well.
For this particular method, I think I would monkey a bit with the String.prototype,
so as to use the built in method where possible.

```
if(!String.prototype.trim){
    String.prototype.trim= function(){
        var start= -1,
        end= this.length;
        while(this.charCodeAt(--end)< 33);
        while(this.charCodeAt(++start)< 33);
        return this.slice(start, end + 1);
    }
}
```

This may indeed be fast, but I prefer simple-

```
if(!(''.trim)){
    String.prototype.trim= function(){
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd expect this to be pretty fast actually, since the replace function is implemented in C, or C++ (whatever the browser is written in).  It's a bit slower inherently because it uses regexps, but being compiled into native code probably more than makes up for that.